# VS2013 always linking to 1.55.0 boost library

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am migrating my code to Visual Studio 2013, Professional (from 2005). For this, I have installed cmake 3.0.2 (previous version 2.8) and compiled boost 1.56.0 (previous version 1.47.0).

CmakeList.txt to find boost is:

```
# find the boost installed path from environment variable
set(BOOST_ROOT_DIR "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT_DIR}")
if(BOOST_ROOT_DIR)
  message( "Boost found at ${BOOST_ROOT_DIR}")
else(BOOST_ROOT_DIR)
  set(BOOST_ROOT_DIR "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}")
  if(BOOST_ROOT_DIR)
  else(BOOST_ROOT_DIR)
    message( FATAL_ERROR "BOOST is not installed")
  endif()
endif(BOOST_ROOT_DIR)
include_directories("${BOOST_ROOT_DIR}")
```

Here, environment variable BOOST_ROOT_DIR is set to path where my boost is installed.

Now, when I am building my project, it is giving me linking error like:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib'
```

The problem I am seeing is, I have compile boost 1.56.0 but it is trying to link with 1.55.0 version library.

i am not able to understand why this is happening.

Please help.

**Edit :** I have compiled my boost using command:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your code need the Boost's `thread` component (others similarly) that you need to include in the `CMakeLists.txt` like:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED thread) # name the needed components explicitly
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(yourProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am not able to understand is, till now I did not need to explicitly name the components (till I was using 1.47.0) but why now I need to mention it?

Also, by doing what you have said, how would it link to 1.56.0 version? Do I need to mention version as well?

Comment: @Garfield No need to mention the version as long as you set the Boost path to `BOOST_ROOT` environment.

Comment: Also note that on VS, Boost will attempt auto-linking the libraries, which can easily break with CMake. So be sure to add `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to your preprocessor defines.